# NUXT.JS Injected Plugin Test

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, nuxt.js

I have created an inject plugin something similar to the one below in Nuxt.js. I need to write test cases for the same using Jest. 
How do I access the injected function 'accountBalance' in jest spec file?

```
export default ({ store }, inject) => {
    inject('accountBalance', () => {
        const accountType = acc => getAccountType(acc, store);

        const func2 = acc => getfun(acc, store, true);

        return { accountType, func2 };
    });
};
```

Comment: I've been looking for solution for this but no luck, so I came up with my own solution of separating the concerns (for now). My goal was that I wanted to test my plugin methods worked properly, and those methods worked within components, so I tested plugin methods by just copy & pasting them into test script directly without nuxt wrapper and tested them, then, I mocked methods and values returned in components test separately.